# UFT - Object Identification not working on Run Time

Tags: hp-uft

I have written a code for Web page. The process requires me to click on a weblink which opens up a new window, then perform some operations on the browser window. Then I close the new browser. This is repeated multiple times in the code. All the elements on all the browser windows are normally identifiable using the object spy. However, intermittently during run time when a new browser window opens up the elements on the page are not getting recognized (hence it throws errors). When i go into the debug mode and try using the object spy the maximum identification i can capture is `Browser(<>).Page(<>)`. Nothing in the page is getting recognized.

Now if i close this browser and reopen it and check again, the elements on the page are getting captured by the object spy and i can continue with my script execution. Sometimes I have to close and reopen multiple times for it to work.

Is there any way to handle this scenario. check for object identifications on the run time maybe. Dunno if it this is any relevant but i am not making use of the OR in my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of UFT are you using?

Comment: i am using UFT 12.02

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in UFT and you should contact HP's support.

A workaround if you know where the problem is probable to appear is to add `Browser("<name>").RefreshWebSupport`. This is an undocumented feature of UFT that [*sometimes* helps in cases like this](http://www.sqaforums.com/printthread.php?Cat=0&Board=UBB20&main=709590&type=thread).